# PHP How can I fix this error? Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class iSerializable

Tags: php

I am having a problem with detecting if an interface class is already declared

*Error reported is:*

**Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class iSerializable in /public_html/application/AppCode/iSerializable.interface.php on line 3**

```
line1: //nothing here
line2:  require_once($filename);    
line3:  interface iSerializable
        {
            public function writeXML(DomDocument $doc, DomElement $element);
        }
```

**If this was a normal class, then i would have used this example function given below**

```
if(class_exists('iSerializable') != true)
{
   //put class iSerializable here
}
```

**but here, this class is an Interface, how can i check if this interface is already declared?**

Can any one kindly suggest me a proper way or solution to this problem?

Comment: Ehem.. [`interface_exists()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.interface-exists.php)?

Comment: You're probably stuck in an include loop. `iSerializable` includes a file that includes `iSerializable` again. **This shouldn't happen**. If your interface doesn't extend another interface, why would you need a `require` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`interface_exists()`](http://php.net/interface_exists)

Answer (score 1):

`interface iSerializable` is an interface, not a class. You are trying to validate if a class exists, which technically it doesn't. A class does not denote an interface.

Look into `interface_exists()`